# Backoung size bug after recaptcha loading

Tags: html, css, background

Hey i have a problem with my html page

I use recaptcha on my website but after recaptcha load i have a problem with backround

Before recaptcha :

[image]

After recaptcha :

[image]

I don t know why but after captcha load the background don t take all page

For my background i use
CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

 #dark-bg {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51,0,102,1) 15%, rgba(67,26,156,1) 90%);
    float: left;
  }

#wave {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50.06%;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Ds3Raj2.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51,0,102,1) 54%, rgba(67,26,156,1) 90%) !important;
}
```

And html

```
<div id="dark-bg"></div>
    <div id='wave'>
        <p></p>
    </div>
```

How i can resolve that?

Comment: Screenshots might be showing empty space in viewport but I cannot tell. Inserting the Recaptcha element changes the height and the width of its container. Presumably you are inserting the element inside the <p>? I’d try giving that container with and height to anticipate rendering the Recaptcha.

Comment: @Rob_M Not work with a predefinied size